# Extra linefeeds around PrintStream.printf() arguments in a server app

Tags: java, printf, printstream

In a plain Java application, this code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
System.out.printf("XXXX %s YYY\n","Something");
System.out.printf("XXXX %s YYY\n","");
System.out.printf("XXXX %d YYY\n",123);
System.out.printf("XXXX %3.3f YYY \n",123.456);
```

Gives this, as expected:

```
1.8.0_131
Oracle Corporation
XXXX Something YYY
XXXX  YYY
XXXX 123 YYY
XXXX 123.456 YYY
```

The very same code, as part of a server app, produces this:

```
1.8.0_131
Oracle Corporation
XXXX 
Something
 YYY
XXXX 
 YYY
XXXX 
123
 YYY
XXXX 
123.456
 YYY
```

In addition, if I remove the XXX/YYY decorations, the output is normal, (except that the line for the null string is not printed at all).

The systems is Ubuntu 16.04, and the server is an IBM WAS Liberty 16.0.0.4, which is really using the OpenJDK runtime above (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java). Now, grep'ing the Liberty jars I see a `org.owasp.esapi.waf.internal.InterceptingPrintWriter.class`, could that be a culprit?

I may be missing something completely obvious or something is done to the PrintStream but I can't see any settings for this.

And yes, I'm going to change the code to use a proper logging framework, so the question is quite academic anyway. Still I'm curious...

With a colleague's help we tested on  Windows (with Java 1.8.0_121):

- With a Liberty server: same problem
- With a Tomcat V7 server: no problem

So the problem would be in the server runtime.

Well, dumping the class hierarchy of System.out:

- in a regular app:

  ```
  java.io.PrintStream
  java.io.FilterOutputStream
  java.io.OutputStream
  java.lang.Object
  ```
- in the Liberty server:

  ```
  com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.BaseTraceService.TeePrintStream
  java.io.PrintStream
  java.io.FilterOutputStream
  java.io.OutputStream
  java.lang.Object
  ```

So, I think I have the beginning of an explanation.

Comment: Can you add more information about the Platform you are on, about server?

Comment: @karna Added required information

Comment: As an aside, it's recommended to use `%n` instead of `\n` with `printf`, for better portability.

Comment: [InterceptingPrintWriter](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/waf/internal/InterceptingPrintWriter.java) doesn't look like the culprit, it just forwards every method call unchanged.

Comment: Are you actually printing "XXXX" and "YYY" verbatim or are these just symbols for the actual things you are printing?

Comment: Verbatim, here. Copy/pasted the code and the output. I'm glad to see you about as baffled as I am :)

Comment: Did some more tests, see question.

Comment: Instead of using printf you could try String.format. Are you actually using System.out? How are you viewing the server output, is it on the same terminal? How do you get the strings?

Comment: @matt Going to use slf4j anyway...